# Implementing a complicated activation function in keras

Tags: keras

I just read an interesting paper: [A continuum among logarithmic, linear, and exponential functions, and its potential to improve generalization in neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01321).

I'd like to try to implement this activation function in Keras.  I've implemented custom activations before, e.g. a sinusoidal activation:

```
def sin(x):
  return K.sin(x)
get_custom_objects().update({'sin': Activation(sin)})
```

However, the activation function in this paper has 3 unique properties:

1. It doubles the size of the input (the output is 2x the input)
2. It's parameterized
3. It's parameters should be regularized

I think once I have a skeleton for dealing with the above 3 issues, I can work out the math myself, but I'll take any help I can get!

Comment: Can you post in details what your activation is supposed to do? (Does it have trainable weights?)

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes, it has trainable weights.  It's an activation that varies between linear, logarithmic, exponential, and sinusoidal output, depending on the values of the trainable weights.

Comment: Then you will have to create a custom class indeed... https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: @DanielMöller I actually found someone trying to implement soft exponential activation as a layer here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3842.  Any idea where they went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, we will need one of these two:

- A Lambda layer - If your parameters are not trainable (you don't want them to change with backpropagation)
- A custom layer - If you need custom trainable parameters.

#### The Lambda layer:

If your parameters are not trainable, you can define your function for a lambda layer. The function takes one input tensor, and it can return anything you want:

```
import keras.backend as K

def customFunction(x):

    #x can be either a single tensor or a list of tensors
    #if a list, use the elements x[0], x[1], etc.

    #Perform your calculations here using the keras backend
    #If you could share which formula exactly you're trying to implement, 
        #it's possible to make this answer better and more to the point    

    #dummy example
    alphaReal = K.variable([someValue])    
    alphaImag = K.variable([anotherValue]) #or even an array of values   

    realPart = alphaReal * K.someFunction(x) + ... 
    imagPart = alphaImag * K.someFunction(x) + ....

    #You can return them as two outputs in a list (requires the fuctional API model
    #Or you can find backend functions that join them together, such as K.stack

    return [realPart,imagPart]

    #I think the separate approach will give you a better control of what to do next.
```

For what you can do, explore the [backend functions](https://keras.io/backend/).

For the parameters, you can define them as keras constants or variables (`K.constant` or `K.variable`), either inside or outside the function above, or even transform them in model inputs. [See details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334788/keras-modifying-lambda-layer-after-compile/47336417#47336417)

In your model, you just add a lambda layer that uses that function.

- In a Sequential model: `model.add(Lambda(customFunction, output_shape=someShape))`
- In a functional API model: `output = Lambda(customFunction, ...)(inputOrListOfInputs)`

If you're going to pass more inputs to the function, you'll need the functional model API.
If you're using Tensorflow, the output_shape will be computed automatically, I believe only Theano requires it. (Not sure about CNTK).

#### The custom layer:

A custom layer is a new class you create. This approach will only be necessary if you're going to have trainable parameters in your function. (Such as: optimize alpha with backpropagation)

Keras [teaches it here](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).

Basically, you have an `__init__` method where you pass the constant parameters, a `build` method where you create the trainable parameters (weights), a `call` method that will do the calculations (exactly what would go in the lambda layer if you didn't have trainable parameters), and a `compute_output_shape` method so you can tell the model what the output shape is.

```
class CustomLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, alphaReal, alphaImag):

        self.alphaReal = alphaReal    
        self.alphaImage = alphaImag

    def build(self,input_shape):

        #weights may or may not depend on the input shape
        #you may use it or not...

        #suppose we want just two trainable values:
        weigthShape = (2,)

        #create the weights:
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=weightShape,
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)

        super(CustomLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self,x):

        #all the calculations go here:

        #dummy example using the constant inputs
        realPart = self.alphaReal * K.someFunction(x) + ... 
        imagPart = self.alphaImag * K.someFunction(x) + ....

        #dummy example taking elements of the trainable weights
        realPart = self.kernel[0] * realPart    
        imagPart = self.kernel[1] * imagPart

        #all the comments for the lambda layer above are valid here

        #example returning a list
        return [realPart,imagPart]

    def compute_output_shape(self,input_shape):

        #if you decide to return a list of tensors in the call method, 
        #return a list of shapes here, twice the input shape:
        return [input_shape,input_shape]    

        #if you stacked your results somehow in a single tensor, compute a single tuple, maybe with an additional dimension equal to 2:
        return input_shape + (2,)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement a "Layer", not a common activation function.

I think the implementation of pReLU in Keras would be a good example for your task. See [pReLU](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py#L49)

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function in the activation worked for me. Maybe not what you want but it's one step more complicated than the simple use of a built-in activation function.

```
encoder_outputs = Dense(units=latent_vector_len, activation=k.layers.Lambda(lambda z: k.backend.round(k.layers.activations.sigmoid(x=z))), kernel_initializer="lecun_normal")(x)
```

This code changes the output of a Dense from Reals to 0,1 (ie, binary).

Keras throws a warning but the code still proves to work.